# Wrong answer on Inversion count?

Tags: c++, mergesort

```
void merge(vector<int> arr, int l, int m, int r,int &count)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    vector<int> L, R;

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L.push_back(arr[l+i]);
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R.push_back(arr[m+1+j]);
     /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            count+=(n1-i);
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
       are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
       are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
   sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(vector<int> arr, int l, int r,int &count)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m,count);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r,count);

        merge(arr, l, m, r,count);
    }
}

int Solution::countInversions(vector<int> &A) {
    int count = 0;
    mergeSort(A,0,A.size()-1,count);
    return count;
}
```

This is my code for counting number of inversions. I have solved this question earliar also, so i am pretty confident about the logic i implemented, i dont know why it is not passing some of the test cases on interview Bit Test Cases. Any help will be appreciated!Thanks.

Your submission failed for the following input:

```
A : [ 84, 2, 37, 3, 67, 82, 19, 97, 91, 63, 27, 6, 13, 90, 63, 89, 100, 60, 47, 96, 54, 26, 64, 50, 71, 16, 6, 40, 84, 93, 67, 85, 16, 22, 60 ]
```

Your function returned the following :

```
372
```

The expected returned value :

```
290
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `count+=(n1-i);`?

Comment: hey @ScottHunter! During merging the array, whenever we encounter an element from second array going to merged array, that means that element has inversion with all the remaining elements of first array i.e. (n1-i).

Comment: So if first array is [10,11] and second array is [1,2], there are 4 "inversions"?  What is your definition of an "inversion"?

Comment: @ScottHunter  for any i and j if a[i] > a[j] and i < j , it will count as an inversion pair.

Comment: An inversion pair counts as 1 or 2

Comment: @SiddharthChabra 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting inversions at every level of the recursion; the question (apparently) is only interested in inversions in the input array.

If I apply your definition of an inversion to the input array, I get the expected return value.

Comment: Isn't the inversion in the input array , is the sum of recursive sum i am applying ?